# xamdatagrid row background color datatrigger

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, infragistics

I'm trying to change the color of my row in Xamdatagrid
I have a boolean which I want to bind into it.

I'm trying to use this 
http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.aspx?ArticleID=10103

here is my code:
I'm having a problem with the style:

```
igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding ResultData}" DataContext="{Binding }" Grid.Row="6"
                          GroupByAreaLocation="None"
                          Width="Auto"
                          ActiveDataItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordCellArea}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Record.DataItem.CanBeCalculated}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                </igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
                <igDP:XamDataGrid.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DisplayImageCommand}"/>
                </igDP:XamDataGrid.InputBindings>
```

**error MC3015: The attached property 'Style.Triggers' is not defined on 'Setter' or one of its base classes.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the **`Style.Triggers`** out of **`Setter`** element.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordCellArea}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/> <-- HERE close the setter.
   <Style.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                     Path=Record.DataItem.CanBeCalculated}" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
     </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: is there a way to change only the resource dictionary background. because now i override the whole template

Comment: Didn't get you. What is resource dictionary background?

Comment: assume i have a custom style which makes all the grid black and the letters blue. now i want to change only the background to red using a datatrigger. the datatrigger overrides the custom style and presents the default style of Xamdatagrid, hwo can i keep my custom style with my datatrigger? is there a designated syntax to use the BaseOn attribute?

Comment: Yeah you have to use `BasedOn` in case you want to inherit values from base style. But, once you override property in derived class, base property won't persist. Syntax - `<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyleKey}"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

this is the answer just putting it here for documentation
thanks Rohit.

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding ResultData}" DataContext="{Binding }" Grid.Row="6"
                          GroupByAreaLocation="None"
                          Width="Auto"
                          ActiveDataItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordCellArea}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type igDP:DataRecordCellArea}}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Record.DataItem.CanBeCalculated}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Tomato"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
```